# How to a deb package without Quickly?

Tags: packaging, gtk3, python-2.7

I am developing an app now, I'm using **GSetting** as my setting back-end, but I can't make my `.gschema` file installed while open the `.deb` file.

I'm wandering if there is some simple guide for green hand like me to packaging deb?

Answer (score 0):

Check these tutorials, they are made by MOTU team.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Videos